# Spring import SQL with Hibernate

Tags: sql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I want to use Hibernate when running the initial sql file. The problem I currently have is that I get the following Exception: I want HIBERNATE to insert the ID instead of the database!

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Field 'id' doesn't have a default value
```

My application.properties looks like this:

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDBDialect
#Data Source Settings
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/kotlin
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.dbcp2.test-while-idle=true
spring.datasource.dbcp2.validation-query=SELECT 1
spring.datasource.continue-on-error=false
#Add Initial Date for Testing
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files=data.sql
```

My User Model contains:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
var id: Long = 0
```

My startup sql script:

```
INSERT INTO user (first_name, last_name, pass_word, user_name, version, email) VALUES ('deepak', 'sp', '$2a$10$2nU5xMCyzPMeNiGQsrjzQeWNcHf9NjtGzVFgy6kVRcZlLh/ABTgZW', 'spdeepak', 1, "example@example.com");
```

It seems like it wants to directly execute the sql (generated ID by Hibernate is not used) instead of creating an User-object and afterwards insert the data.

I ALSO get this error when dealing with default values (It says there is no default value on database). So please don't just answer with "Use GenerationType.IDENTITY)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO user (id, first_name, last_name, pass_word, user_name, version, email) 
VALUES 
(null, 'deepak', 'sp', '$2a$10$2nU5xMCyzPMeNiGQsrjzQeWNcHf9NjtGzVFgy6kVRcZlLh/ABTgZW', 'spdeepak', 1, "example@example.com");
```

Your insert statement is missing id column, but it is required. If you provide null value, then db will assign its value automatically by usign autoincrement.

About id generation by hibernate for manual scripts - it is impossible. Manual scripts are executed as is directly to the database without any framework. It is pure jdbc statement sql script execution.

I see that your are using jpa repositories according to your properties files. If you want id generation to be made by hibernate then you should create your user through jpa repository.

Comment: Hibernate should do that for me instead of the database... Thats the actual question. But anyway, thank you.

Comment: Hibernate can do nothing with manual scripts. you should either insert your user with jpa repository or provide valid script for the database. Because manual scripts are executed as is.

Comment: This is the answer i wanted to hear. Add that to your answer and I will accept it